# How can I make the "Look In" field in a JFileChooser editable on WIndows?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have a simple jFileChooser for opening files. This is the code:

```
    JFileChooser diagOpen = new JFileChooser(myFolder);

    diagOpen.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    if (diagOpen.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        return diagOpen.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    else
        return null;
```

This is the result:

[image]

My system is in spanish and I'm using Windows 7 with Java 8. What I need is to make the field "Buscar en" ("Look in") editable, so the user can write her desired path and be redirected there when pressing enter (this is how the default Windows Open dialog works).
I perused the properties and options of the jFileChooser, and read several tutorials, but I can't find how to do it.

I tried the option `jFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I perused the properties and options of the jFileChooser,

There is no property that allows you to do this.

> I need is to make the field "Buscar en" ("Look in") editable,

You could use the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class to access the combo box of the file chooser and make it editable.

The code would simply be:

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
JComboBox jComboBox = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JComboBox.class, jFileChooser).get(0);
jComboBox.setEditable(true);
jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

However, this still won't solve the problem because whatever the user types will be saved as a `String` in the combo box and the file chooser is expecting a `File` object so I get a `ClassCastException` when I try it.

But it may get you one step closer to solving your problem.